# How to enable Apache Ignite REST API on Springboot application?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jetty, ignite

I'm developing distributed computing application with Apache Ignite and Springboot and wanna use ignite REST API.

Below is my dev spec.
java 1.8
springboot 1.5.6
ignite 2.1.0

I added dependency ignite-rest-http(2.1.0 ver.) on my pom file.
But there is one problem at starting my springboot application.
Here is error log.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.Ignite]: Factory method 'igniteInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog.setProperties(Ljava/util/Properties;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog.setProperties(Ljava/util/Properties;)V
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.http.jetty.GridJettyRestProtocol.<clinit>(GridJettyRestProtocol.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor.startHttpProtocol(GridRestProcessor.java:864)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor.start(GridRestProcessor.java:477)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startProcessor(IgniteKernal.java:1788)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:937)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1896)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1648)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1076)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:574)
    at org.apache.ignite.IgniteSpring.start(IgniteSpring.java:66)
    at com.ssg.framework.config.ignite.IgniteDefaultConfiguration.igniteInstance(IgniteDefaultConfiguration.java:59)
    at com.ssg.framework.config.ignite.IgniteDataConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$84d5bde0.CGLIB$igniteInstance$7(<generated>)
    at com.ssg.framework.config.ignite.IgniteDataConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$84d5bde0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a827740d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at com.ssg.framework.config.ignite.IgniteDataConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$84d5bde0.igniteInstance(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

In StdErrLog class, there is not 'setProperties(Properties)' method, but is called in GridJettyRestProtocol class.
I can't understand how it was built without syntax error.
Anyway, is there anyone who has solution?

============================================================================
I added my pom file below.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy-agent</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spring-data</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-urideploy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lazyluke</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4jdbc-remix</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.openhft</groupId>
        <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.esotericsoftware</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflectasm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-rest-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: can you add your pom file?

Comment: @Konstantin I added my pom. thnx

Comment: I agree with answer below: you got conflict between different Jetty versions. To resolve dependency conflicts you can use [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)

Comment: Thanks @Konstantin, I solved problem by excluding jetty dependencies from spring-boot and adding 9.2.11.v20150529 version.

Answer (score 1):

`ignite-rest-http` module depends on Jetty 9.2.11.v20150529. Your error most likely means that there is already another version of Jetty on classpath and they conflict with each other. You should check your Maven (or Gradle, etc.) project go get to the bottom of this.

Comment: I added my pom file and I checked dependency hierarchy, but couldn't find any another version of jetty. Could you give me more help?

Comment: Try to use [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you use spring boot 2.0.0+ then it has a dependency on jetty-bom which is only available in maven central since v9.3.19...
Ignites 2.6.0 uses jetty 9.2.11...
A quick and dirty workaround is to setup jetty like this, where jetty.base.version is the version Ignite uses. ex Ignite v2.6.0 this = 9.2.11.v20150529.
This way the jetty-bom gets resolved but not used.
The correct jetty libs for Ignite are loaded.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-bom</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.12.v20180830</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-continuation</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.base.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.base.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.base.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.base.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.base.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.base.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Having similar issue with Solr testing and embedded Jetty, which requires Jetty 9.2.x.  I tried excluding jetty-bom from spring boot, but it does not appear to respect the exclusion.   So I'll proceed with the brute force approach.  Just to be clear, you have to use a different property name than ${jetty.version}, which is picked up by Spring Boot.